# Latest CA Certificate Authorities List

Tags: certificate-authority

I am posting this question after checking this question 
[Where can I find all SSL CA certificates](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42946/where-can-i-find-all-ssl-ca-certificates)

I need to verify couple of CA authorities.(below)

```
CloudFlare
NameCheap
AWS
commodo
```

Where can in find updated list of CA Authorities, or what is the easiest way to verify CA Authority.

Comment: Asking for a list of things (especially a list that changes over time) is off topic here.  I'd suggest that you reword your question so that it's _only_ asking for how to verify a known root CA.

Comment: i am asking for current list . i think that should be answered

Comment: Then if that's what you're asking for, this question will be closed as off topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an online public list of generally trusted certificate authorities?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158259), [List of certificate authorities in browsers and mobile platforms](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/49006),